# Intune new office installation on already installed office

Tags: microsoft-intune

Currently users have office 365 installed via een msi that was inserted into Intune. We now want to use the new method because than we can easily add and remove applications.

Is it possible to do so? because right now we have tested by assigning the new application to the user. But when they have outlook open for example the install fails.

Any solution how we can do this?

Comment: Someone? that can help?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this XML configuration, which we use to force a particular installation of Office 365. When using the Intune Office installation wizard, we struggled whenever various pieces and parts of Office were pre-installed on new devices.

The parts that force the installation would be; Display Level="None", AcceptEULA, RemoveMSI, MigrateArch, ForceUpgrade, FORCEAPPSHUTDOWN.

For more information see [Microsoft's Office Deployment Tool documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/configuration-options-for-the-office-2016-deployment-tool).

```
<Configuration>
  <Info Description="Install Office 365 ProPlus 64-bit, with Visio and Project." />
  <Display Level="None" AcceptEULA="TRUE" />
  <RemoveMSI />
  <Add OfficeClientEdition="64" MigrateArch="TRUE" Channel="Monthly" ForceUpgrade="TRUE">
    <Product ID="O365ProPlusRetail">
      <Language ID="MatchOS" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Groove" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="OneDrive" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="OneNote" />
    </Product>
    <Product ID="VisioProRetail" > 
      <Language ID="MatchOS" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Groove" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="OneDrive" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="OneNote" />
    </Product>
    <Product ID="ProjectProRetail" > 
      <Language ID="MatchOS" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Groove" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="OneDrive" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="OneNote" />
    </Product>
  </Add>
  <Property Name="SharedComputerLicensing" Value="1" />
  <Property Name="PinIconsToTaskbar" Value="FALSE" />
  <Property Name="FORCEAPPSHUTDOWN" Value="TRUE"/>
  <Updates Enabled="TRUE" Channel="Monthly" />
  <AppSettings>
    <Setup Name="Company" Value="ACME, Inc." />
  </AppSettings>
</Configuration>
```